# How do you make a command where you can save and load messages

Tags: node.js, save, load

I'm trying to make a command where you can save and load messages. It does save the message, but the load isn't working. Could someone help me?

```
    let savedmessages = [
  {"name":"CurseForge", "message":"Hello World!"}
]

  const args = message.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

      if (cmd==="loadmsg") {
    messagecount++;
    let text = args[0];
    for(var message in savedmessages[text]){
      if(savedmessages[text].hasOwnProperty("name")){
      if(savedmessages[text].hasOwnProperty("message")){
         return bot.chat(text + ': ' + savedmessages[text]["message"]);
      }
    }
    }
  bot.chat("--The username you have specified doesn't have any messages saved.")
  }
```

Any answer would be greatly appreciated! Thanks. If you are wondering, those are 3 sections of the code and not the full one as the only problematic section is the load message command.

Comment: Is the content of `args[0]` numeric?
If `0` is present, `savedmessages[text]` means:
`{name: "CurseForge", message: "Hello World!"}`
This is an object type, so there is no need `for`.

Comment: Yes, it is. It gets the first argument the player supplies. I'm looking to get the message though.